# Error when using Generics with JUnit 4 Theories

Tags: java, generics, junit, junit4

I am encountering a strange error when trying to mix generics with JUnit 4 Theories. My code is below. What I am basically trying to do is write a single method that tests subtypes of the Comparable Interface. Even though the method should accept any subtype of comparable, only one subtype should be tested at a time (thus, Strings and Integers - both subtypes of Comparable - should never be tested together).

Just as a reference, this is an assignment which explicitly requires the use of the Theories and generics, so I cannot use a different part of JUnit, or omit the use of generics.

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class ComparableTheory{

    @DataPoints public static String[] stringPoints() {
            return new String[] {
                    "abc",
                    "acc"
            };
    }

    @DataPoints public static String[] stringPoints2() {
            return new String[] {
                    "xyz",
                    "mno"
            };
    }

    @DataPoints public static Integer[] integerPoints() {
            return new Integer[] {
                    1, 2, 3
            };
    }

    @Theory
    public <T extends Comparable> void comparableTransitiveTheory(T a, T b, T c) {
            assumeTrue (Math.signum(a.compareTo(b)) == Math.signum(b.compareTo(c)));
            assertTrue (Math.signum(a.compareTo(c)) == Math.signum(a.compareTo(b)));
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is below:

```
JUnit version 4.13-beta-2
.E
Time: 0.002
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(ComparableTheory)
org.junit.runners.model.InvalidTestClassError: Invalid test class 'ComparableTheory':
1. Method comparableTransitiveTheory() contains unresolved type variable T
2. Method comparableTransitiveTheory() contains unresolved type variable T
3. Method comparableTransitiveTheory() contains unresolved type variable T
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:511)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:91)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:74)
at org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories.<init>(Theories.java:73)

FAILURES!!! 
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

As a reference, I am running and compiling with the following commands:

```
javac -cp .:"*" ComparableTheory.java
java -cp .:"*" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ComparableTheory
```

The files `hamcrest-2.1.jar` and `junit-4.13-beta-2.jar` are in my working directory (and thus, in my classpath).

Comment: how do you run this class in eclipse?

Comment: @RayTayek Thank you for your response - I don't run it in Eclipse; I am running from the command line. I include the JUnit and Hamcrest jars in my classpath.

Comment: how do you run from the command line? can you share incatation?

Comment: you might need to use: T extends Comparable<T>

Comment: @RayTayek Unfortunately, T extends Comparable<T> did not work - I still received the same error message. Also, I just edited my post - near the bottom are the commands I am running from the command line.

Comment: where did you find junit-4.13-beta-2.jar? all i can find is the source.

Comment: never mind, found it at: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.13-beta-2

Comment: i am getting the same error as you.